# Authentication ExpressJS -> passportJs: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am doing authentication in expressjs using passportjs. Here is my code of login.js

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
      function(username, password, done) {
        //console.log(username);
        Usercollection.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
          }
          else{
            return done(null, user);
          }
          // if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
          //   return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
          // }

        });
      }
    ));
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user);
    });
    router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/automation-panel',
      failureRedirect: '/'
      })
    );
```

and users.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){  next(); }else {res.redirect('/');}
    // var sess = req.session;
    // if(sess.username != null){
    //  // res.send("hello "+ sess.username);
        // console.log(req.user.username);
    // }
    // else{
    //  req.redirect('/');
    // }
    // res.sendFile("fileUpload.html");
    // res.send("hello success");
    res.render('users/index', { title: 'Express'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

and error in detail is

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:690:11
```

Comment: do you still get the error if you remove `res.render('users/index', { title: 'Express'});` it might be because you may have already ran `res.redirect('/');`

Comment: yes. i get the error if i comment res.render(...); and even i am getting error if i console.log('hello');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.render('users/index', { title: 'Express'});
    }
    else return res.redirect('/');
});
```

if problem continues, you have another redirection somehow. so maybe this line is the problem.

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/automation-panel',
    failureRedirect: '/'
    })
);
```

Comment: I think you are right. When an user makes `POST /` and fails, then it get redirected to `GET /` with `302 -Moved Temporarily` header. And then in `GET /` route it sets redirect header again in `res.redirect('/')`. Actually there is should be recursive redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render('users/index', { title: 'Express'});
    }else {
        // Remove Below line. otherwise it will create infinite redirect loop.
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```